# error: invalid input syntax for type date: "" using NodeJS and PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm inserting data into my database using NodeJS. If a user doesn't enter a value for date then `""` will be sent to the database. If I do that it's gives me this error `error: invalid input syntax for type date: ""` What can I do in case of this?

```
const addAlbum = (request, response) => {
 const { title, date, description, id } = request.body;

 for (let i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {
  db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON 
  CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *' , [request.body[i].title, request.body[i].date, 
  request.body[i].description, request.body[i].id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    } else {
      console.log('INSERT ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    }
  })
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, `request.body[i].date` is a string, also if the corresponding column type  in the table is `date` type, it should be `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You should be able to store date string value converting it to a date object. Try changing  `request.body[i].date` to:

```
new Date(request.body[i].date);
```

You can do the following exercise to play around:

```
const createTableText = `
CREATE TEMP TABLE dates(
  date_col DATE,
  timestamp_col TIMESTAMP,
  timestamptz_col TIMESTAMPTZ,
);
`
// create our temp table
await client.query(createTableText)
// insert the current time into it
const now = new Date()
const insertText = 'INSERT INTO dates(date_col, timestamp_col, timestamtz_col) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)'
await client.query(insertText, [now, now, now])
// read the row back out
const result = await client.query('SELECT * FROM dates')
console.log(result.rows)
// {
// date_col: 2017-05-29T05:00:00.000Z,
// timestamp_col: 2017-05-29T23:18:13.263Z,
// timestamptz_col: 2017-05-29T23:18:13.263Z
// }
```

Source: https://node-postgres.com/features/types